# Scrape SVG HTML

Tags: html, vba, svg, scrape

I am wondering if anyone could tell me if this is possible as I've hit a bit of a brick wall. Not looking for someone to do this for me, just a nudge in the right direction would be great.

I'm scraping the [link](http://epl.squawka.com/english-barclays-premier-league/17-05-2016/man-utd-vs-b-mouth/matches) using VBA.

More specifically I'm trying to scrape the circle tag co-ordinates of the SVG element. I am able to drill down to the div class `sqw_icons` no problem.

I can return the properties of the SVG, such as height and width. But I can't seem to work out a way to get to the g class elements beneath that.

My impression is that it's possible because they are HTML Collections.

Any ideas would be very useful.

Here is the code:

```
Sub ImportSqw()

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As HTMLDocument

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = False
    ie.Navigate "http://epl.squawka.com/english-barclays-premier-league/17-05-2016/man-utd-vs-b-mouth/matches"

    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set html = ie.Document
    Set ie = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    Cells.Clear

    Dim levelOne As IHTMLElement
    Dim levelTwo As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim levelThree As IHTMLElement
    Dim levelFour As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim levelFive As IHTMLElement
    Dim levelSix As IHTMLElementCollection

    Set levelOne = html.getElementById("mc-pitch-view")
    Set levelTwo = levelOne.Children

    For Each levelThree In levelTwo
        If levelThree.className = "sqw_pitch_container" Then
            Set levelFour = levelThree.Children
        End If
    Next

    For Each levelFive In levelFour
        If levelFive.className = "sqw_icons" Then
            Set levelSix = levelFive.Children
        End If
    Next

    Set html = Nothing

End Sub
```

The item in `levelSix` doesn't have Children properties.

Comment: Show us some code. There shouldn't be problems iterating over `children`.

Comment: You shouldn't have removed the structure from your question - hard to tell if the code is correct now :D

Comment: apologies, ive only signed up there now, it only lets me post one link! Would you like me to re-post?

Comment: Can't you just embed the important html (or svg) bits into your question? It's always better to have everything needed for the question and answer inside of the question (for off-site resources may vanish at any time).

Comment: if you click on the "shots" tab in the link and inspect a circle it will take you to the structure I posted :-D

Comment: As for js this is giving me the g-elements: `$('#mc-pitch-view > div.sqw_pitch_container > div.sqw_icons > svg').children('g')` --- what's your issue exactely? You need to traverse the DOM to the svg and then select the g's.

Comment: Apologies, I should say that I have only been learning this since yesterday so I'm not entirely au fait with how this works. How do I 'traverse' the DOM with VBA?

Comment: I gave you the nudge, now go search the interwebs for some VBA tutorials ;)

Comment: haha thanks for your help. Looking already!